# Saving plot from seaborn

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, seaborn

When I try to save my plot working with seaborn, like this:

```
import seaborn as sn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import savefig

array = [[100,0], 
        [33,67]]

df_cm = pd.DataFrame(array)

svm = sn.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True,cmap='coolwarm', linecolor='white', linewidths=1)

svm.savefig('svm_conf.png', dpi=400)
```

I get this error

```
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-71-5c0ae9cda020> in <module>()
----> 1 svm.savefig('svm_conf.png', dpi=400)

AttributeError: 'AxesSubplot' object has no attribute 'savefig'
```

I have saved some boxplots before, with the same code, but this time, it doesn't work.

Comment: you want `plt.savefig('svm_conf.png', dpi=400)`

Comment: I tried that option, but I got the same error. :(

Comment: Are you working in something like an ipython interactive session? - Maybe start a new session and copy the code. Using plt.savefig should definitely not give the same error.

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Actually what you would need to do is:

- Retrieve the figure from the object returned by [`sn.heatmap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.heatmap.html)
- Then and only then save the figure

See the last 2 lines below:

```
import seaborn as sn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from pylab import savefig

array = [[100,0], 
        [33,67]]

df_cm = pd.DataFrame(array)

svm = sn.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True,cmap='coolwarm', linecolor='white', linewidths=1)

figure = svm.get_figure()    
figure.savefig('svm_conf.png', dpi=400)
```

Comment: @MosteM Thanks for the confirmation, I removed the erroneous message in my post.

Comment: `plt.savefig` works well in windows and IPython. [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GApVb.png). I don't know what you did to break it, but there is at least no reason to claim that it would not work.

Comment: @ImportanceOfBeingErnest Indeed, my bad then, I guess it's specific to my current environment then

Comment: Small note: If you are saving a seaborn `ClusterGrid`, then it won't have a `get_figure()` method. In this case, you save directly with `svm.savefig()`

Comment: Not working for me. It says svm has not attribute `get_figure()`

Answer (score 11):

The command to save the current figure would be

```
plt.savefig()
```

Because that apparently causes some confusion, here is the full working example:

```
import seaborn as sn
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

array = [[100,0], 
        [33,67]]

df_cm = pd.DataFrame(array)

svm = sn.heatmap(df_cm, annot=True,cmap='coolwarm', linecolor='white', linewidths=1)

plt.savefig('svm_conf.png', dpi=400)
```

Answer (score 4):

The easiest way would be to use

```
plt.savefig('svm_conf.png', dpi=400)
```

instead of

```
svm.savefig('svm_conf.png', dpi=400)
```

Comment: Funny enough, using IPython and Windows yields a blank image. Using Python directly does indeed yield the chart. Perhaps you could add this to your post

Comment: That's strange, I tested the script with IPython on a Linux system and it saves the image.

Comment: The method `svm.get_figure().savefig()` works in both cases though